# Mount samba share from konsole

Tags: linux, mount, samba

I have samba share with null password enabled in gui nautilus i can easily access for cp/write/delete by smb://192.168.0.100/homenet with no pass asked,  but when i try mount this share with `#mount.cifs //192.168.0.110 /mountpoint` i'm asked for password

```
mount error(13):Permission denied
```

wich pass is wanted?

Comment: Try this `mount -t smbfs //hostname/share /mountpoint`

Comment: no this give me _uknown filesystem smbfs_. I think the truc would be done with mount.cifs

Comment: Get solved mount.cifs //192.168.0.110/share /mountpoint. This was question of smb.conf
**security=SHARE** when previous was =USER that option do pass asking